# MSGraph read shared mailbox messages through app service

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am writing an api using the msgraph api which should be able to read mail from shared mailboxes.  I have setup the application in Azure and have given the following permission (my app is running as its own service and not on behalf of an user)

[image]

What I am confused about is

1. Why does it show `Delegated`, all the rest of my permissions to the application show `Application`.
2. Since this is an application how does an user share a particular mailbox with this application, what I can think of is to create a service account, then this application impersonates that service account and then uses the service account to access the shared mail, but this sounds like a really complicated process and am wondering if I'm heading down the correct path.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Microsoft graph permissions reference, [Mail Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#delegated-permissions-34) `Mail.Read.Shared` and `Mail.Send.Shared` require a signed in user which is why the permissions show up as delegated. To the best of my knowledge, there isn't currently a way to access shared mailboxes via Ms graph without a signed in user.

Please let me know if this helps, and if you have further questions.

Comment: so that means using the service I need to use a generic account to log in and then use that generic account token by the service to read the mail off the shared mailbox?